# How to lock the application orientation to portrait in 4.6.3

Tags: qt, symbian

I would like to restrict my application to portrait orientation. I was able to it in Qt 4.7.3 but was unable use the same code for Qt 4.6.3.
Is there any way to setOreintation in Qt 4.6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Symbian specific code to meet your requirement. Add the following code in your Main.cpp file:

```
// Symbian specific code
    #ifdef Q_OS_SYMBIAN
    CAknAppUi* appUi = dynamic_cast<CAknAppUi*> (CEikonEnv::Static()->AppUi());
    TRAPD(error, 
    if (appUi) {
        // Lock application orientation into Portrait
        appUi->SetOrientationL(CAknAppUi::EAppUiOrientationPortrait);
    }
    );
    #endif
```

Also the following LIBS in your pro file:

```
LIBS += -lcone -leikcore -lavkon
```

Refer this [LINK](http://asmncl.blogspot.in/2012/05/qt-for-symbian-lock-application.html) for more details.